# python TypeError adding time using timedelta

Tags: python

I'm trying to add time. eventually I will create a function passing different times and I want to change the time. For some reason I can't make timedelta to do it.

this is my code:

```
time1 = datetime.time(9,0)
timedelta = datetime.timedelta(minutes=15)
time2 = time1 + timedelta
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.timedelta'
```

what should i change?

Comment: timedelta objects can only be added to datetime.datetime objects, not datetime.time objects.

Comment: I think you need a `datetime.datetime` object in order to add a timedelta

Comment: Okay so how can I change a datetime.time object instead of manually define it every time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only add a `timedelta` to a `datetime` (as pointed out by Ben). What you can do, is make a `datetime` object with your time and then add the `timedelta`. This can then be turned back to and `time` object. The code to do this would look like this:

```
time1 = datetime.time(9,0)
timedelta = datetime.timedelta(minutes=15)
tmp_datetime = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date(1, 1, 1), time1)
time2 = (tmp_datetime + timedelta).time()
```

Answer (score 1):

`time` objects don't participate in arithmetic by design:  there's no compelling answer to "what happens if the result overflows?  Wrap around?  Raise `OverflowError`?".

You can implement your *own* answer by combining the `time` object with a `date` to create a `datetime`, do the arithmetic, and then examine the result.  For example, if you like "wrap around" behavior:

```
>>> time1 = datetime.time(9,0)
>>> timedelta = datetime.timedelta(minutes=15)
>>> time2 = (datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(), time1) +
        timedelta).time()
>>> time2
datetime.time(9, 15)
```

Or adding 1000 times your delta, to show the overflow behavior:

```
>>> time2 = (datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(), time1) +
        timedelta * 1000).time()
>>> time2
datetime.time(19, 0)
```